# Ajax returns success but doesn't change the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a small script of js to edit a profile in the way facebook used to be (click a button, edit and save without reloading the page). The problem is that when I run it, the ajax function returns sucess but akes no changes on the database. The function os js is this:

```
$('.savebtn').click(function(){
            var editdata    = $(".editbox").val();
            var parameter   = $(this).closest("td").find("#parameter").text();

            var datastring  = "data="+editdata+"&parameter="+parameter;

            var $t = $(this);

            console.log(datastring);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL + "/API/update_profile.php",
                data: datastring,
                cache: false,
                success: function()
                {
                    $t.closest('td').find('.curr_value').html(editdata);
                    $t.closest('td').find('.curr_value').hide;
                    console.log(editdata);
                    $(this).prev(".edit").hide();
                    $(this).prev(".curr_value").show();
                    $(this).prev('.edit_link').show();
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

(Ignore the $t thing, somehow this works like this, but not if I use $(this))

Ajax executes the code for sucess but doesn't update anything on the database.

The PHP code for the database is:

```
<?php

include_once("../../config/connect_db.php");
include_once("../../database/cliente.php");

$parameter = $_POST['parameter'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

var_dump($_POST);

try {
    updateProfile($parameter, $data, $id);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

?>

```
function updateProfile($parameter, $data, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE biofood.users 
                            SET ? = ?
                            WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($parameter, $data. $id));
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out, this could be a problem with trying to pass a column name as a parameter. Changed the code to the following, but with no sucess:

```
function updateProfile($parameter, $data, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $query = "UPDATE biofood.users 
              SET $parameter = $data
              WHERE id = $id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Your `$(this)` does not work, because `this` loses context in your `success()` function. You can define a variable like you already do, declare a variable such as `self` and assign `this` to it, or use the new ES6 arrow function syntax which maintains the context in your success function.

Comment: @MarioTacke The $(this) is working. On the javascript part everything is working, the problem is that the db is not updated

Comment: This initial comment was not to answer the question but to clarify the context of `this` in your success callback. What you are doing *is* working because you assign `$(this)` to `$t` outside of your ajax call. I was merely trying to describe why `this` changes within the success function. :)

Comment: **What happens if the user enters a COLUMN NAME that does not exist on this table????**

Comment: Second attempt at the query needs `SET $parameter = '$data'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the column name is not entered by the user ;)

Comment: Well in that case What is `$parameter` because it is in a position that denotes a column name in that query

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$stmt->execute(array($parameter, $data. $id));
```

I think should be

```
$stmt->execute(array($parameter, $data, $id));
```

(notice the comma after `$data`)

Comment: Nice catch! Unfortunately, not enough :S

Comment: Have you logged your `$id` parameter? The update will go through even if it doesn't affect any records if the where condition excludes the set you want to update. Log it and run a select query manually with where id = your id from the log.

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your problem, but it might give you a better indication on where your problem is.

First, you are not checking whether it works or not as your `updateProfile` function returns nothing.

Modify your `updateProfile` function, so that it returns the number of rows affected. (BTW this is a safer way to write your function. If you can check or limit the value of $parameter prior to calling this function, it will be less prone to SQL injection.)

```
function updateProfile($parameter, $data, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE biofood.users SET $parameter = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($data, $id));
    return $stmt->rowCount(); // # of rows affected
}
```

In the script that calls this function, get the value and send it back as a response. We'll send back a JSON.

```
$response = array();
try {
    $response['success'] = updateProfile($parameter, $data, $id);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

In your JavaScript file, make the following change:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: BASE_URL + "/API/update_profile.php",
     data: datastring,
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {
         if (data.success) {
             $t.closest('td').find('.curr_value').html(editdata);
             $t.closest('td').find('.curr_value').hide;
             console.log(editdata);
             $(this).prev(".edit").hide();
             $(this).prev(".curr_value").show();
             $(this).prev('.edit_link').show();
             $(this).hide();
         }
     },
     dataType: 'json'
});
```